# Issue with bindings on attached properties in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, attached-properties

**EDIT:** Please, do not post answers on how to implement gestures in Xamarin.Forms - read the entire post first.

I'm creating a swipe gesture handlers as effects using the attached properties (as described in [Xamarin guides](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/passing-parameters/attached-properties/)). Skipping the approach discussion I have a strange issue with attached properties implementation.

Long story short (code below) - **XAML bindings to attached properties are not working**. The `Set\Get...Command` methods in my static class are not executed at all. I don't see any `Debug.WriteLine()` result in app output. The debugger doesn't hit the breakpoints set there as well. The same with `...CommandPropertyChanged()` handler.

This is my class for the properties handling:

```
namespace Core.Effects
{
    public static class Gesture
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty SwipeLeftCommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.CreateAttached("SwipeLeftCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Gesture), null, propertyChanged: SwipeLeftCommandPropertyChanged);

        public static readonly BindableProperty SwipeRightCommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.CreateAttached("SwipeRightCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Gesture), null, propertyChanged: SwipeRightCommandPropertyChanged);

        public static ICommand GetSwipeLeftCommand(BindableObject view)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("GetSwipeLeftCommand");
            return (ICommand) view.GetValue(SwipeLeftCommandProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSwipeLeftCommand(BindableObject view, ICommand value)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SetSwipeLeftCommand");
            view.SetValue(SwipeLeftCommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static ICommand GetSwipeRightCommand(BindableObject view)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("GetSwipeRightCommand");
            return (ICommand) view.GetValue(SwipeRightCommandProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSwipeRightCommand(BindableObject view, ICommand value)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SetSwipeRightCommand");
            view.SetValue(SwipeRightCommandProperty, value);
        }

        private static void SwipeLeftCommandPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SwipeLeftCommandPropertyChanged");
            // ...
        }

        private static void SwipeRightCommandPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SwipeRightCommandPropertyChanged");
            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

and here is how I use it in XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:Core.Effects"
             x:Class="Core.Pages.RequestDetailsPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="0"
                     Padding="0"
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     effects:Gesture.SwipeLeftCommand="{Binding NavigateToPreviousRequestCommand}"
                     effects:Gesture.SwipeRightCommand="{Binding NavigateToNextRequestCommand}">
```

I have corresponding commands in my view model (MVVM implemented with FreshMvvm framework):

```
namespace Core.PageModels
{
    public class RequestDetailsPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
    {
        public IRelayCommand NavigateToNextRequestCommand;
        public IRelayCommand NavigateToPreviousRequestCommand;
```

`IRelayCommand` is my type deriving from `ICommand`. The `BindingContext` is properly set by FreshMvvm (works well in other places on this view).

Any clue what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was pretty simple (and pretty hard to track either). Bindings do not operate on fields but on properties:

```
namespace Core.PageModels
{
    public class RequestDetailsPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
    {
        public IRelayCommand NavigateToNextRequestCommand {get; set;}
        public IRelayCommand NavigateToPreviousRequestCommand {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done sample repo on GitHub, Check Below Link.

https://github.com/softlion/XamarinFormsGesture

https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleCustomGestureFrame

http://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thank you for the answer but my question was not how to implement the swipe gesture (I've seen those solutions and they helped me to implement other parts) but **why the attached properties are not working**
Regarding the first repo - it's not functional because of the [still opened issue](https://github.com/softlion/XamarinFormsGesture/issues/2)

Comment: are you create renderer?

Comment: No, I don't. Please read the entire question (and my comment) carefully once again

Comment: Try this 
public RelayCommand NavigateToNextRequestCommand { get; set; }

with  
 NavigateToNextRequestCommand = new RelayCommand(NavigateToNextRequestCommand);

Comment: The commands are already initialized in view model constructor (not shown for brevity)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work (just checked). Why do you thing it should?

Comment: https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm/blob/master/samples/FreshMvvmSampleApp/FreshMvvmSampleApp/PageModels/MainMenuPageModel.cs

Comment: OK, understood. So like I wrote, it's not the case. I'm also using the interfaces for command fields in other view models with standard bindings (on non-attached bindable properties) and they are working fine.